# Forms on procedure in apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I want to create form on procedure in APEX 
this is my code

```
create or replace procedure "RESERVER2"
  (numo_place in number,CATGE IN varchar,NOM_EQUIP1 IN VARCHAR2,NOM_EQUIP2 IN VARCHAR)
  is

  V_MAX CLIENT1.MAXIMUM%TYPE;
  V_MIN CLIENT1.MINIMUM%TYPE;
  V_CATG CLIENT1.CATG%TYPE;
  V_NOM_EQUIPE1 CLIENT.NOM_EQUIPE1%TYPE;
  V_NOM_EQUIPE2 CLIENT.NOM_EQUIPE2%TYPE;
  V_num  reservation.num_place%type;

  CURSOR C1 IS 
    select CATG,NOM_EQUIPE1,NOM_EQUIPE2 from client1;

begin 

  open C1;

  LOOP 

    FETCH C1 into V_CATG,V_NOM_EQUIPE1,V_NOM_EQUIPE2;

    EXIT WHEN C1%notfound;

    select CATG into V_CATG from CLIENT1;

    if CATGE=V_CATG THEN

      INSERT INTO RESERVATION(CATEG)values(CATGE); 

      select NOM_EQUIPE1 into V_NOM_EQUIPE1 from CLIENT1;

      if NOM_EQUIP1=V_NOM_EQUIPE1 THEN

        INSERT INTO RESERVATION(NOM_MATCH)values(NOM_EQUIP1);

        if CATGE='A'AND numo_place<20 then

          select NOM_EQUIPE2 into V_NOM_EQUIPE2 from CLIENT1;

          if NOM_EQUIP2=V_NOM_EQUIPE2 THEN

            INSERT INTO RESERVATION(NOM_MATCH2)values(NOM_EQUIP2);

            if CATGE='A'AND numo_place<20 then
              INSERT INTO RESERVATION(NUM_PLACE) values(numo_place);
            else
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERREUR');
            end if;

          end if;

        end if;

      end if;

    end if;

  end loop;

  close C1;

end;
```

When I run my form  and I start fill the text field after I click in submit
this error appears:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Any advice?

Comment: One of your `SELECT` statements returns more than one record, you are trying to assign the return into a variable, if there are more than one records returned by the select this error is thrown.

Comment: I want to select from table client1 ,( in this table exist so many rows)

Comment: Then you'll need to either restrict the rows returned with a `WHERE` clause or return the rows into a collection.

Comment: Your main loop queries the `client1` table; why then do you do all those queries on the same table again?

Comment: It seems to me that you actually should use the procedure parameters (e.g. `CATGE`) as predicates in your initial query on `client1`, instead of querying all the rows from the table and then comparing the values in the loop.